# How to remove the pattern string until there is no pattern string in the text?

Tags: java, string, string-matching

> **Problem Descripition**
>
> You are given 2 strings,`text` and `pattern` , you should do the following operations
>
> 1. If `pattern` is not in `text`, goto **4**
> 2. delete the first occurrence of `pattern` in `text`
> 3. goto **1**
> 4. print current `text`
> 5. end

I try to solve this problem using **KMP Algorithm**. I find the `delete` operation will cost much time, so I use another `textNext` array to store the next element's index of `text` string to skip the `pattern` string in `text`(avoiding really deleting it from `text`). For example, `text` is `ukpkmkk`, and the `pattern` is `pk`. After executing the operations, `textNext` should be `{1,4,3,4,5,6,7}`(`textNext` is initialized to **i+1** for element). I use the code below to traverse the string after those operations.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i = textNext[i]) {...}
```

My problem is that I can't get the correct result using my algorithm. Here is my code.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = in.next();
        String pattern = in.next();
        int[] textNext = new int[text.length()];
        for (int i = beginIndex; i < textNext.length; i++) {
            textNext[i] = i + 1;
        }

        while (kmp(text, pattern, textNext) != -1) {}

        for (int i = beginIndex; i < text.length(); i = textNext[i]) {
            out.print(text.charAt(i));
        }
        out.println("");
        out.close();
    }

    public static int kmp(String text, String pattern, int[] textNext) {
        int[] patternNext = buildNext(pattern);
        int head = 0;
        for (int i = beginIndex, j = 0; i < text.length(); i = textNext[i]) {
            while (j > 0 && text.charAt(i) != pattern.charAt(j)) {
                j = patternNext[j - 1];
            }
            if (text.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j)) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    head = i;
                }
                j++;
            }
            if (j == pattern.length()) {
                if (head == 0) {
                    beginIndex = i + 1;
                } else {
                    textNext[head - 1] = i + 1;
                }
                return head;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int[] buildNext(String pattern) {
        int[] next = new int[pattern.length()];
        next[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
            while (j > 0 && pattern.charAt(i) != pattern.charAt(j)) {
                j = next[j - 1];
            }
            if (pattern.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j)) {
                j++;
            }
            next[i] = j;
        }
        return next;
    }
```

Please point out where my algorithm's problem is or just offer other way to solve this problem.

Comment: One problem is that KMP won't help you here.  Consider finding "aba" in "aabababa".  KMP will find the text at positions { 1, 3, 5 }, but your answer should find one match at position 1, then backtrack to find the second match at position 0.

Comment: I don't understand how your algorithm is related to the problem description. For a string `ukpkmkk` and a pattern `pk`, don't you just need to print `ukmkk`?

Comment: For a string that is complicated, the situation is different, For example, text is `uujjklklpp`, pattern is `jkl`. After deleting tha pattern for the first time, the text is `uujklpp`, and there is still a pattern string, so you need to delete pattern from text again and get `uupp`. For a string that is very long, delete the pattern from text may cost much time so I want save some time for the deleting operation